# ES2015 promises - what am I missing?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I expected the following to print `1 2 3`. But it prints `1 undefined 3`. What am I missing?

```
var p = Promise.resolve('2');

new Promise(resolve => { console.log('1'); resolve(); })
  .then(p)
  .then((result) => console.log(result, '3'));
```

Comment: You must pass functions to `then`, not promises.

Comment: I recall you asking questions regarding monads. A `Promise` is a monad (a weird one though). It is a context or container for future values. You can't combine two contexts/containers in a meaningful way by themselves, expect maybe to nest them. But `then` (which is just `chain` or `bind`) is exactly implemented in a way to avoid nested `Promise`s. Because `then` is just `chain` you can pass functions to it that return a Promise. Monadic functions expect a value and return a monad.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to wrap the `p` variable in an anonymous function

```js
var p = Promise.resolve('2');

new Promise(resolve => { console.log('1'); resolve(); })
  .then(() => p)
  .then((result) => console.log(result, '3'));
```